# What's the problem with $-2=(-8)^{\frac{1}{3}}=(-8)^{\frac{2}{6}}=\sqrt[6]{(-8)^{2}}=2$?

Tags: roots, square-numbers

$-2 =(-8)^{\frac{1}{3}} = (-8)^{\frac{2}{6}} = \sqrt[6]{(-8)^{2}}=2$ 
 first glance I want to show for $a^{rs}$ to work, both $a^r$ and $a^s$ need to be valid, but as you can see, both $-8^{\frac{1}{3}}, -8^{\frac{2}{2}}$ is defined. so I wanna know how do I prove the above statement is wrong

Comment: Exponentiation for negative bases is not well-defined.

Comment: it is defined on $Q_{odd}=\{\frac pq\mid \gcd(p,q)=1\text{ and }q\text{ odd}\}$, but you break the gcd condition at second equal sign.

Comment: For complex numbers, roots result in multiple solutions and, contrary to the case of positive real numbers, one has $(z^{n})^{1/n} \neq z$. Thus, also the first equal sign is wrong, because the 3rd root has three solutions. And, the third equal sign  is wrong because you go from 3 to 6 solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The sixth root of a number is considered even and for any even root, the answer can be positive or negative. You pick which one is best fit or both, which in this case is -2 as shown from your starting point.

Another issue is by stating that -2=2, you imply that 0=4 or 0=1, which is a tell-tale sign something is wrong.

Comment: Starting from something we know is false, we can expect anything we want, so "something is wrong" should not be written. What really happens is that if we know that we did steps that are correct and we find a contradiction (like $-2=2$ or $0=4$ or $0=1$), then we **must** care about how the math is written (all math would be wrong). Good news: We haven't found such case yet!